# Timeouts on Cloud SQL and other external services when using NAT + IP Masquerade on GKE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, nat, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I have to configure a static IP in one of my PODs because a remote service (outside of my cluster) requires trusted IP whitelisting.

I followed the documentation provided by Google:

https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview?hl=es-419

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent

But when trying to configure egress traffic using Google cloud NAT service in my GKE cluster plus masquerading using the `ip-masq-agent` I start getting timeouts and problems when accessing remote services outside of the cluster.

My Cluster is in version `1.19.10-gke.1600`.

I have tried these config files with the following results:

```
resyncInterval: 60s
```

Result:

```
Chain IP-MASQ (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             10.0.0.0/8           /* ip-masq-agent: local traffic is not sub
ject to MASQUERADE */
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             172.16.0.0/12        /* ip-masq-agent: local traffic is not sub
ject to MASQUERADE */
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             192.168.0.0/16       /* ip-masq-agent: local traffic is not sub
ject to MASQUERADE */
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* ip-masq-agent: outbound traffic is sub
ject to MASQUERADE (must be last in chain) */
```

The services keep using the wrong IP.

---

```
resyncInterval: 60s
masqLinkLocal: true

Chain IP-MASQ (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             169.254.0.0/16       /* ip-masq-agent: local traffic is not sub
ject to MASQUERADE */
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             10.0.0.0/8           /* ip-masq-agent: local traffic is not sub
ject to MASQUERADE */
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             172.16.0.0/12        /* ip-masq-agent: local traffic is not sub
ject to MASQUERADE */
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             192.168.0.0/16       /* ip-masq-agent: local traffic is not sub
ject to MASQUERADE */
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* ip-masq-agent: outbound traffic is sub
ject to MASQUERADE (must be last in the chain) */
```

The same effect, my outside services get the wrong IP.

---

```
nonMasqueradeCIDRs:
  - 0.0.0.0/0
resyncInterval: 60s
masqLinkLocal: true

Chain IP-MASQ (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* ip-masq-agent: local traffic is not sub
ject to MASQUERADE */
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* ip-masq-agent: outbound traffic is sub
ject to MASQUERADE (must be last in the chain) */
```

It looks this works better because the external services receive the correct IP but I get connection problems and timeouts.

---

This is my NAT configuration:

```
NAT mapping
- High availability: Yes
- Source subnets & IP ranges: All subnets' primary and secondary IP ranges
- NAT IP addresses: static-egress-ip XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

I'm out of ideas, can someone give me any advice?

---

After the response got here I updated my config file to add the ips following google cloud documentation, the file goes like this:

```
nonMasqueradeCIDRs:
  - 10.0.0.0/8
  - 172.16.0.0/12
  - 192.168.0.0/16
  - 100.64.0.0/10
  - 192.0.0.0/24
  - 192.0.2.0/24
  - 192.88.99.0/24
  - 198.18.0.0/15
  - 198.51.100.0/24
  - 203.0.113.0/24
  - 240.0.0.0/4
resyncInterval: 60s
masqLinkLocal: true
```

The result of this in the iptables is:

```
Chain IP-MASQ (2 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             10.0.0.0/8           /* ip-masq-agent: local traffic is not sub
ject to MASQUERADE */
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             172.16.0.0/12        /* ip-masq-agent: local traffic is not sub
ject to MASQUERADE */
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             192.168.0.0/16       /* ip-masq-agent: local traffic is not sub
ject to MASQUERADE */
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             100.64.0.0/10        /* ip-masq-agent: local traffic is not sub
ject to MASQUERADE */
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             192.0.0.0/24         /* ip-masq-agent: local traffic is not sub
ject to MASQUERADE */
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             192.0.2.0/24         /* ip-masq-agent: local traffic is not sub
ject to MASQUERADE */
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             192.88.99.0/24       /* ip-masq-agent: local traffic is not sub
ject to MASQUERADE */
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             198.18.0.0/15        /* ip-masq-agent: local traffic is not sub
ject to MASQUERADE */
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             198.51.100.0/24      /* ip-masq-agent: local traffic is not sub
ject to MASQUERADE */
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             203.0.113.0/24       /* ip-masq-agent: local traffic is not sub
ject to MASQUERADE */
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             240.0.0.0/4          /* ip-masq-agent: local traffic is not sub
ject to MASQUERADE */
MASQUERADE  all  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* ip-masq-agent: outbound traffic is sub
ject to MASQUERADE (must be last in chain) */
```

But if I run a curl `checkip.amazonaws.com` to see what IP is being used by the node I get a different IP from the one defined in my NAT Cloud configuration and the external services reject request as non trusted from my cluster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally we were able to diagnose the problem. Our cluster was created some time ago when GCP didn't supported private clusters so our clusted is public.

Each node have a public ephemeral IP thus the NAT rules are being ignored.

The solution was setting a node with a static IP and not ephemeral and configuring the workload that requires trusted auth to always deploy on that specific node. This is not a perfect solution but is what we can do quickly to solve the problem.

The real solution would be migrating to a private cluster and configuring the NAT but sadly GCP does not support migration from a public cluster to a private one. The only option would be creating a new cluster an migrate the workloads to the new cluster, process that we will need to execute in the short term.

Maybe it is a good moment to test autopilot which does not support automate migration too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have set the `nonMasqueradeCIDRs:` as 0.0.0.0/0 thereby preventing Masquerading of all the CIDR traffic, so to fix this issue, in the config file update the nonMasqueradeCIDRs: key with the IPs mentioned in Defaut non-masquerade destination paragraph [1]  as given below.

nonMasqueradeCIDRs:

- 172.16.0.0/12
- 192.168.0.0/16
- 100.64.0.0/10
- 192.0.0.0/24
- 192.0.2.0/24
- 192.88.99.0/24
- 198.18.0.0/15
- 198.51.100.0/24
- 203.0.113.0/24
- 240.0.0.0/4
- 10.0.0.0/8

Also please note that the IPs referred in the screenshot were not wrong IPs but those are ranges reserved by RFC 1918/link-local i.e., the IPs 10.0.0.0/8, 172.16.0.0/12 192.168.0.0/16 are reserved for RFC 1918 and the IP range 169.254.0.0/16 is reserved for link-local and these are non-masqueradable and hence these IPs are being displayed with the description ‘ip-masq-agent: local traffic is not subject to masquerade’[2].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ip-masquerade-agent#default-non-masq-dests

[2]
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/ip-masq-agent/#ip-masquerade-agent-user-guide

Regards,
Anbu.

Comment: Hi @Anbu, thanks a lot for the help. I followed your instructions and instead of using 0.0.0.0/0 as masq I put the ranges defined in the documentation. You can see the editions made to my question to see the output of the commands but I still have the problem that my nodes and pods are calling the external services using an IP that I don't control. The NAT fixed IP I configured in GOOGLE CLOUD NAT is ignored. I'm testing this with a curl directly from the node ssh or calling my external services wich return IP unallowed. Any Ideas?